# Pyinstaller: Exe files do not run; encoding error

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, exe, pyinstaller

Edit: Due tu being marked as duplicate= 
My problem is not related to pyinstaller not being supported, same problem persist in cx_Freeze 3.7

for some reason my .exe files don't run.

```
C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile>pyinstaller -F Test.py
72 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
72 INFO: Python: 3.7.0
72 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
72 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile\Test.spec
72 INFO: UPX is not available.
72 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Fif\\Desktop\\Python\\To compile',
 'C:\\Users\\Fif\\Desktop\\Python\\To compile']
72 INFO: checking Analysis
87 INFO: Building because pathex changed
87 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
87 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
87 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3634 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
3649 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\python37\python.exe
3681 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python.exe
3712 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python.exe
3728 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python.exe
3759 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python.exe
3774 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python.exe
3978 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
3993 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
4023 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
4039 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
4055 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
4086 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
4102 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
4133 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
4148 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
4180 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
4211 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
4227 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\python37.dll
4258 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\VCRUNTIME140.dll
4273 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\VCRUNTIME140.dll
4305 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\VCRUNTIME140.dll
4320 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\VCRUNTIME140.dll
4336 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\VCRUNTIME140.dll
4336 INFO: Caching module hooks...
4352 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile\Test.py
4352 INFO: Loading module hooks...
4352 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
4461 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
4461 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
4742 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
4742 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
4758 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
4774 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
4805 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
4852 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
4867 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
4883 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
4914 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
4930 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
4961 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
4989 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
5010 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
5025 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
5057 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
5088 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
5104 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
5119 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
5151 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
5182 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
5213 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
5229 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\_socket.pyd
5276 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\select.pyd
6394 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
6425 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
6441 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
6472 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
6488 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
6504 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
6535 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
6550 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
6582 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
6597 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
6644 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
6675 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
6691 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
6707 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
6707 INFO: Looking for eggs
6707 INFO: Using Python library c:\python37\python37.dll
6707 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
6722 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile\build\Test\warnTest.txt
6769 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile\build\Test\xref-Test.html
6785 INFO: checking PYZ
6785 INFO: Building because toc changed
6785 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile\build\Test\out00-PYZ.pyz
7451 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile\build\Test\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
7451 INFO: checking PKG
7451 INFO: Building because C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile\build\Test\out00-PYZ.pyz changed
7451 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
9158 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
9158 INFO: Bootloader c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
9158 INFO: checking EXE
9174 INFO: Rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because pkg is more recent
9174 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
9174 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile\dist\Test.exe
9174 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
```

This is how it looks like when I run it

C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile>cd C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile\dist

```
C:\Users\Fif\Desktop\Python\To compile\dist>Test.exe
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000005d0 (most recent call first):
```

Steps I have done so far.

-formated my PC and fresh installed everything (my pc was a mess, so i needed to do it anyway and I expected this to be a cause)

-run everything as admin

-uninstalled and reinstalled everything

-made VM with win7, installed python3.4.3, got the exactly same error

-tried multiple files to make into exe (current is literally just a print 
command)

Honestly, I have no clue what else to do, any help would be appriciated

Comment: `formated my PC and fresh installed everything` is definitly not the problem.  You need to somehow include the `encodings` module.

Comment: acccording to research I did, encodings module should be installed with python install, there is a butt ton of encondings files in my python install, but I have no clue what to do with them

Comment: Yes it is installed.  You need to include those files when you generate your exe.

Comment: How about pip install encodings?

Comment: I have never used Pyinstaller so I do not know exactly how to do that.  however I have had this problem with cx_Freeze (similar software)

Comment: @HoseongJeon  No it is installed already.

Comment: @Simon Do you have an idea how? Pyinstaller should take care of this by itself. So how do I make it use encodings, which encoding file should ut be?

Comment: Depends.  For security I generally include the whole encodings file (but it can be refined later) Looks like you need the [-v](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#getting-python-s-verbose-imports) flag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872724/zipimport-zipimporterror-cant-find-module-encodings)

Comment: @SImon, that was asked months ago, back whem 3,7 was not even out, or right after launch. 

I have tried manipulating with --path, to encodings folder, but there is like 17.... Any idea which encoding should be used?

Comment: You will need a bunch of them.  Best include the whole `encodings` module.  Off hand I would say definitly UTF-8

Comment: @Simon. I don't know, what you mean by "including encodings module", include where, where do i find it.

Anywho, I have tried cx_Freeze and this is the result

C:\Python37\build\exe.win-amd64-3.7>test.exe


Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: invalid flags 1530064918 in 'encodings'


Current thread 0x0000207c (most recent call first):

Comment: Include it when you create your exe, there should be an option that allows you to add it.  You should find it at `<Path to Python>/Python37/Lib/encodings`